# Why the tyre at near-side kerb makes noise when I balance on hill road?

Tags: tires, noise, automatic-transmission, parking-brake

I drive Honda Jazz 2010 model semi-automatic.

When I stop at a road with slope (hilly), I apply my parking brake and switch my gear from A1 (automatic 1st gear) to N (Neutral).

When I am about to begin driving, I do the following steps:

1. Press the car brake pedal, switch the gear from N to A1.
2. Press accelerating pedal to get car balancing.
3. Once I feel the car has the momentum to drive, I release the parking brake and start driving.

At the end of step 3, I heard the tyre at the Near-Side of my car (not sure front or rear) makes some noise. I feel the noise coming from the front near-side.

Then the noise goes away when I continue driving.

That noise only shows when I start driving from a hilly road after applied parking brake.

I know my tyre at NSR (near-side rear) has 3mm tread and it is due

Questions:
1) Why there is noise from the near-side tyre? Should I be worried about it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you try and describe the noise for us?

Comment: @motosubatsu, the tyre noise is like scratching. Hard to describe. The closest example of the noise is a racing car making the tyre noise when it is about to drive.

Comment: I guess you are spinning the near side wheel when you start. Either the tire pressures at the front are not equal, the tire tread depths are very different, or you are using too much gas pedal before you release the brakes.